# Path connected implies connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness, path-connected

I am learning point set topology, and I want to be able to prove that a path connected set is also a connected set. I found many results by searching, but none of which I understand fully. One stands out from [topospaces wiki](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=path%20connected%20set%20is%20connected&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8):

> Given: A path-connected topological space $X$
>
> To prove: $X$ is connected.
>
> Proof: We do this proof by contradiction. Suppose $X$ is not
> connected. Then, there exist nonempty disjoint open subsets $U, V \subseteq X$ such that $X=U \cup V$. Pick a point $x \in U$ and a
> point $y \in V$.
>
> By assumption, there exists a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. $\color{blue}{\text{Consider the subsets $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$. These are disjoint in $[0,1]$ and their union is $[0,1]$}}$. By the continuity of $f$, they are both
> open in $[0,1]$. Finally, since $0 \in f^{-1}(U)$ and $1 \in f^{-1}(V)$, they are both nonempty. We have thus expressed $[0,1]$ as
> a union of two disjoint nonempty open subsets, a contradiction to the
> fact that $[0,1]$ is connected. This completes the proof.

I understand all parts of this proof except for the highlighted blue part. I do not know why the inverse images of two open disjoint sets in $X$ are also disjoint in $[0,1]$, and union to equal it. Is there some general property inverse images which means that inverse images of disjoint open sets are also disjoint? If so, why? (i.e. is there a proof?)

Comment: Yes, if $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ is any function between sets (nothing to do with topology) and $M,N\subseteq B$, then $f^{-1}(M\cap N)=f^{-1}(M)\cap f^{-1}(N)$ and $f^{-1}(M\cup N)=f^{-1}(M)\cup f^{-1}(N)$. I highly encourage you to try and prove these identities yourself if you don't know them.

Comment: @Thorgott I came across that while trying to find proofs, but I was unable to do a proof by expanding everything into its definition (e.g. $f^{-1}[B]=\{x \in X: f(x) \in B\}$). It made intuitive sense though, since an inverse image $f^{-1}[B]$ returns everything that the image $f$ could be input to return $B$. So if $B$ is the union of $C$ and $D$, it will return everything that could result in members from $C$ or $D$. Which is the same as returning everything that could result in members from $C$, in a union with everything that could result in members from $D$. How could it be anything else?

Comment: The reason why I dropped that line of working toward a proof though, was how could I know that the sets where disjoint? However I have just realised that the inverse image of the empty set is the empty set, which allows me to complete the proof provided I have one for the result you suggest I work on.

Comment: If $x\in f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(V)$ then $f(x)\in U$ and $f(x)\in V$, contradicting that $U,V$ are disjoint. For all $x$, $f(x)\in X$ so either $f(x)\in U$ or $f(x)\in V$. Then either $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ or $x\in f^{-1}(V)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\color{blue}{\text{Consider the subsets $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$. These are disjoint in $[0,1]$ and their union is $[0,1]$}}$

We prove the text in blue, where $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, $X=U\cup V$, and $f$ is a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.

---

First we show that $f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$, and $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$, as per a comment by Thorgott. We do this using the definitions of inverse images, set union, set intersection, in set builder notation.

- The union of two sets $A\cup B$ is $\{x|x\in A\text{ or }x\in B\}$.
- The intersection of two sets $A\cap B$ is $\{x|x\in A\text{ and }x\in B\}$.
- The inverse image $f^{-1}(A)$ is defined to be $\{x\in X|f(x)\in A\}$. Inverse images are defined for all functions, invertible or otherwise.

We then have:

\begin{align}
z\in f^{-1}(A\cup B) &\iff f(z)\in A\cup B\\
&\iff f(z)\in A\text{ or }f(z)\in B\\
&\iff z\in f^{-1}(A)\text{ or }z\in f^{-1}(B)\\
&\iff z\in f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)\\
\\
\therefore~f^{-1}(A\cup B)=&f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
z\in f^{-1}(A\cap B) &\iff f(z)\in A\cap B\\
&\iff f(z)\in A\text{ and }f(z)\in B\\
&\iff z\in f^{-1}(A)\text{ and }z\in f^{-1}(B)\\
&\iff z\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)\\
\\
\therefore~f^{-1}(A\cap B)=&f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)
\end{align}

---

It remains to be shown that the subsets $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$. These are disjoint in $[0,1]$ and their union is $[0,1]$. We use the fact that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, and that $f$ maps $[0,1]$ to $X=U\cup V$ to demonstrate this.

\begin{align}
f^{-1}(U)\cup f^{-1}(V)&=f^{-1}(U\cup V)\\
&=f^{-1}(X)\\
&=[0,1]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(V)&=f^{-1}(U\cap V)\\
&=f^{-1}(\emptyset)\\
&=\{x\in [0,1]|f(x)\in \emptyset\}\\
&=\emptyset\\
\end{align}

$\therefore$ $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are disjoint, and their union is equal to $[0,1]$.